# These or they? What should have been used?

Tags: they

> Working papers are the connecting link between the client’s records and the audited accounts. These provide permanent historical record. These also serve as a great guide to the staff to whom the work of audit has been assigned after the previous year audit. These would come to the help of the auditor in future in case the client files a suit against the auditor’s negligence.

Is *these* used in the above paragraph correct or should it have used *they* instead of *these*?

Comment: This is the second question on the same obscure piece of text. Please read the pages describing the scope of this site and consider whether your questions are really pertinent.

Answer (score 2):

It would be most natural to use the demonstrative *these* the first time, and thereafter the basic pronoun *they*.

There's nothing wrong grammatically with what you've written, but stylistically, it invites the reader to ask "Why does the writer keep emphasising that it is these same papers that are being talked about? What's so important about it being precisely *these* papers, when there aren't any others in the context anyway?"